# Trying to establish a generic type for TypeScript EventListeners and get a strange error

Tags: typescript

Why does `tsc` throw the following error and how could I fix this?

> error TS2322: Type '(ev: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '<T extends Event | ErrorEvent | AnimationEvent | UIEvent | DragEvent | MouseEvent | FocusEvent | KeyboardEvent | ... 5 more ... | WheelEvent>(ev: T) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'ev' and 'ev' are incompatible.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent'.
> Type 'Event | ErrorEvent | AnimationEvent | UIEvent | DragEvent | MouseEvent | FocusEvent | KeyboardEvent | ... 5 more ... | WheelEvent' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent'.
> Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 20 more.
> 1 let f: <T extends GlobalEventHandlersEventMap[keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap]>(

```js
let f: <T extends GlobalEventHandlersEventMap[keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap]>(
  ev: T
) => void = (ev: MouseEvent) => console.log()
```

Thank you!

Comment: The type of `f` claims be a handler for lots of event types, but the value you assign to it only handles `MouseEvent`, so it's an error.  What are you *trying* to do?  Maybe you want a generic type and not a generic function, like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgCQIYDsAmAbCAnAHgBUoIAPYCLAZygHFs4AjVbAUQDcrg0tc9qnbgFlUYANoBrCCDgAzeoxbsu6Hhhz5Bq4KLABdAHxQAvFAAUEDgC4oRAJSnjHOAEtMAbgBQAYzjpqYChqRBQNflMoYlIKKkxaBmZWITVeTQEU3TEpGXlFJJVuNP5tETEjcwALcPxbeCRi-GJDRxNjar58b1wghTMQhpq8c0sbKGE4AFdqCEzW4z8AuFwAOkYAc3N7e28Ael2oHqg5OtDGwgnp2Z1DLyA)?

Comment: If so I'll write it up; it not, please elaborate.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz sorry for the delay. I just wanted to do:
`type SomeHandler<
  T extends GlobalEventHandlersEventMap[keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap]
> = (ev: T) => void;
let f: SomeHandler<MouseEvent> = (ev: MouseEvent) => console.log()
`. 
And thanks to your help this works perfectly, thank you very much! It is probably somewhere out there but I could not find such a simple and clean solution anywhere on the internet.